# How to use your own styles in Quantikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, quantikz

I am using the `quantikz` package to draw a quantum circuit and I am failing to insert my "own" gate (BS) as a quantum gate. The gate noisy is a working example of what I want to insert in the second gate. Can anyone help me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\tikzset{pics/.cd, splitter/.style={code={\draw[ultra thick] (#1:{sqrt(1/2)}) --
(#1+180:{sqrt(1/2)});}},splitter/.default=45}

\tikzset{pics/.cd, BS/.style={code={
\draw[->](-1,0)--(1,0);
\draw[->](0,-1)--(0,1);
\path (0,0) pic{splitter};
}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) pic{BS};    
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
noisy/.style={starburst,fill=yellow,draw=red,line
width=2pt,inner xsep=-4pt,inner ysep=-5pt}
}

\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{$\ket{0}$}
&\gate[2]{D}
&\gate[1, style={noisy}]{L_{1,1}}\\         % noisy is working
\lstick{$\ket{0}$}
&
&\gate[1, style={BS}]{L_{1,2}}              % BS is not working
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you show what you would the output to look like? You seem to want to use a `pic` as shape for a node, which does not work, but you could try with `BS/.style={path picture={ ... }}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wonder why adding the style `noise` to the `\gate` command works, but your custom style `BS` does not. Let me try to come up with an explanation to this that is hopefully easy to understand.

Ti*k*Z knows shapes which can be used to style a node. The default shape is `rectangle` and this is what you see, for example, for the node that contais the *D*. Another, much more complicated shape is `starburst` which you use to style the upper right node. So, the style `noise` is a style that changes the *shape* of the node which is added to the diagram using the `\gate` command.

Now, there are also `pic`s, which are so to say small fractions of a larger Ti*k*Z picture. A `pic` can be used in cases where pieces of code are to be reused often. A `pic` can contain nodes and paths, but a `pic` is itself not a node and it is also not a shape. Therefore, if you define your style `BS` as being the defintion of a `pic` (which you do with `pics/.cd, BS/.style`), this style won't do anything sensible to a node. A node doesn't know what to do with a `pic` and you will get an error.

But what you actually could do is to place the `pic` (alone or together with some other paths) as `path picture` to the node, which means that the path you give as value to the `path picture` option is added to the background of the relevant node. You only need to make sure that the `path picture` is scaled properly and sits at the right position and that the node is large enough to show the whole picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/.cd, 
    splitter/.style={
        code={
            \draw[ultra thick] (#1:{sqrt(1/2)}) -- (#1+180:{sqrt(1/2)});
        }
    },
    splitter/.default=45
}

\tikzset{BS/.style={
    draw=none,
    minimum width=1cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    path picture={
        \begin{scope}[x=0.5cm, y=0.5cm]
        \draw[->] (path picture bounding box.center) +(-1,0) -- +(1,0);
        \draw[->] (path picture bounding box.center) +(0,-1) -- +(0,1);
        \path (path picture bounding box.center) pic {splitter};
        \end{scope}
    }
}}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    noisy/.style={
        starburst,
        fill=yellow,
        draw=red,
        line width=2pt,
        inner xsep=-4pt,
        inner ysep=-5pt}
}

\begin{quantikz}
\lstick{$\ket{0}$}
    & \gate[2]{D}
    & \gate[1, style={noisy}]{L_{1,1}} \\ 
\lstick{$\ket{0}$}
    &
    & \gate[1, style={BS}]{L_{1,2}}              
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]